Diffraction cone visualization
I have a problem visualizing the diffraction cone for rays coming from different sides:

Although I've read multiple papers on the topic, my math skills aren't strong enough to fully grasp it, as I'm still an undergrad.
I understand that diffracted rays start around the specular reflection and form a Keller's cone around the specular ray:

Could you explain how it should look in $3{\rm D}$ when the ray is coming from the side ?. This is what I understand. I understand how to define the cone for the first image, I just cannot figure out how would diffraction look like, if the ray was not in the same plane as the edge.



My problem
Edit: I really do not understand how should I approach the situation with modelling a 3D Keller's cone for every possible angle under which the ray intersects with the edge of the wall(any sharp edge). I have an idea, but I am not sure it is right. Is there a formula which could help me with this calculation? Thanks to everyone who is willing to help me understand this.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
